AgoraRTC video disabling and re-enabling is not working as expected
I'm using agora-rtc-sdk-ng in my nextJs project. I have successfully made connection between 2 users.
Suppose there are 2 users in a channel: user1, user2. I try to turn the camera off for user1, it works fine on both user sides. But when I again turn the camera on for user1, user1 can see his video feed properly but user2 still sees an empty video of user1.
How can I fix this? I'm providing the code below:
agora.ts
async connectToAgoraRtc(
    userId: string,
    roomId: string,
    token: string,
    onVideoConnect: any,
    onWebCamStart: any,
  ) {
    const { default: AgoraRTC } = await import("agora-rtc-sdk-ng");
    const client = AgoraRTC.createClient({
      mode: "rtc",
      codec: "vp8",
    });
    await client.join(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AGORA_APP_ID as string,
      roomId,
      token,
      userId
    );
    client.on("user-published", (themUser, mediaType) => {
      client.subscribe(themUser, mediaType).then(() => {
        if (mediaType === "video") {
          onVideoConnect(themUser.videoTrack);
        }
        if (mediaType === "audio") {
            themUser.audioTrack?.play();
        }
      });
    });

    client.on("user-unpublished", () => {
      console.log("user left");
    });

    const tracks = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks();
    onWebCamStart(tracks[1]);
    await client.publish(tracks);
    this.rtcClient = client;
    this.tracks = tracks;
    return { tracks, client };
  }
}

Main.tsx
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import CollapseComponent from "./CollapseComponent";
import VideoSection from "./VideoSection";
import toast, { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import agoraInstance from "@/lib/agora";
import { RtmChannel } from "agora-rtm-sdk";
import { ICameraVideoTrack, IRemoteVideoTrack } from "agora-rtc-sdk-ng";

export default function Main() {
  const [open, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [themVideo, setThemVideo] = useState<IRemoteVideoTrack>();
  const [myVideo, setMyVideo] = useState<ICameraVideoTrack>();

  const rtmChannelRef = useRef<RtmChannel>();

  const session = useSession();
  const userId = (Math.random() * 1000).toString();


  const joinRoom = async () => {
    setThemVideo(undefined);
    try {
      if(userId) {
        //#region Get tokens
        const rtcToken = await agoraInstance.getRtcToken("123", userId);
        const rtmToken = await agoraInstance.getRtmToken(userId);
        //#endregion

        //#region Connect to RTM        
        rtmChannelRef.current = await agoraInstance.connectToAgoraRtm(userId, "123", rtmToken, setMessages);
        //#endregion

        //#region Connect to RTC
        await agoraInstance.connectToAgoraRtc(
          userId, 
          "123",
          rtcToken,
          (themVideo: IRemoteVideoTrack) => setThemVideo(themVideo), 
          (myVideo: ICameraVideoTrack) => setMyVideo(myVideo),
        );
        //#endregion
      } else {
        toast.error("user not logged in properly, please re-login");
      }
    } catch(e: any) {
      console.log(e.message);
      toast.error("error joining room, please try again later");
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Toaster />
      <div className="flex gap-10 h-[80vh]">
        <div className={open ? "w-[60%]" : "w-[100%]"}>
          <VideoSection getRoom={joinRoom} myVideo={myVideo} themVideo={themVideo} />
        </div>
        <CollapseComponent open={open} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} messages={messages} channel={rtmChannelRef} setMessages={setMessages} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

VideoSection.tsx
export default function VideoSection({
  getRoom,
  myVideo,
  themVideo,
}: {
  getRoom: any;
  myVideo?: ICameraVideoTrack;
  themVideo?: IRemoteVideoTrack;
}) {
  const [trackState, setTrackState] = useState({ video: true, audio: true });
  const myRef = useRef(null);
  const themRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const playerRef = myRef.current;
    if (!myVideo) return;
    if (!playerRef) return;

    myVideo.play(playerRef);
  }, [myRef, myVideo]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const playerRef = themRef.current;
    if (!themVideo) return;
    if (!playerRef) return;

    themVideo.play(playerRef);
  }, [themRef, themVideo]);

  const mute = async (type: "video" | "audio") => {
    if (type === "audio" && agoraInstance.tracks) {
      await agoraInstance.tracks[0].setEnabled(!trackState.audio);
      setTrackState((prev) => {
        return { ...prev, audio: !prev.audio };
      });
    } else if (type === "video" && agoraInstance.tracks) {
      await agoraInstance.tracks[1].setEnabled(!trackState.video);
      setTrackState((prev) => {
        return { ...prev, video: !prev.video };
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <div className="h-[150px] w-[225px] absolute bottom-0 right-0 bg-base-200 border outer border-primary rounded-lg z-[1000]">
        <div
          ref={myRef}
          className="border outer border-primary rounded-lg z-[1000]"
          style={{
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            zIndex: "inherit",
            overflow: "hidden",
          }}
        >
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="bg-base-200 rounded-lg h-[65vh] z-[999]">
        <div
          ref={themRef}
          className="rounded-lg"
          style={{
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            zIndex: "inherit",
            overflow: "hidden",
          }}
        >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex gap-3 mt-5">
        <ActionButton
          icon={<BsFastForwardCircleFill size={25} />}
          func={() => getRoom()}
          tooltipData="skip to next stranger"
        />
        <ActionButton
          icon={
            trackState.video ? (
              <BsCameraVideoFill size={25} />
            ) : (
              <BsCameraVideoOffFill size={25} />
            )
          }
          func={() => mute("video")}
          tooltipData="open/close camera"
        />
        <ActionButton
          icon={
            trackState.audio ? (
              <BsMicFill size={25} />
            ) : (
          <BsMicMuteFill size={25} />
            )
          }
          func={() => mute("audio")}
          tooltipData="open/close mic"
        />
        <ActionButton
          icon={<BsPersonFillAdd size={25} />}
          func={() => {}}
          tooltipData="add friend"
          disabled={!themVideo}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

